# Obtaining the Green's function for a 2D Poisson equation ( in polar coordinates)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I am trying to solve the following BVP within an annular region of radii $r_1$, and $r_2$ :
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla^2u=f\\
u(r_1) = p\\ u(r_2) = q
\end{cases}
$$
If we define an auxiliary problem in terms of Green's function as
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla^2G=\delta^2(r-r')\\ 
G(r_1) = 0 \\ 
G(r_2) = 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
We have the solution of u (as given by Green's identities as)
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{\operatorname{d}\!}
u = \oint u  \frac{\partial G}{\partial n} \Dm S + \int Gf \Dm V   \tag{Eqn. A}
$$
How do I proceed to obtain the form of the Green's function ?

I understand that G for a finite boundary problem is done by superposition :

$G = G_{Freespace} + G_{Homogeneous}$

From my little searching I found that,
$G_{Freespace} = Aln(r-r')$, and
$G_{Homogeneous}=a_0 + a_nr^ncos(n\phi) + b_nr^nsin(n\phi)$

However, the expected solution ( from a paper) that I am seeking is of the form:

$2\pi G=H_0 (r_1,r_2) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n(r_1,r_2) cos(n(\phi_1 - \phi_2))$

The form of $H_0$ and $H_n$ are given in the attachment below.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPz88.png)

How do I obtain the solution above from the problem posed ?

Comment: Hint: In $\mathbb R^2$ the Green function is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\log\frac{1}{|x-y|}$.

Comment: I think the solution you gave is for infinite domain. What I want is for a bounded domain and in polar coordinates.

Comment: Please check this paper out : [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06404).

Comment: Its too difficult for me to comprehend